# I ran npm run dev on cmd but it loaded SyntaxError:

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, project

I wanted to create laravel login and registration system.
I run

1. `composer require laravel/jetstream`
2. `php artisan jetstream:install livewire`
3. `npm install`
4. `npm run dev`

After running npm run dev I got the below SyntaxError

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token`    {
`at new Script (vm.js:80:7)`
`at createScript (vm.js:274:10)`
`at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)`
`at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)`
`at Object.Module._extensions..js` `(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)`
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)`

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KmAN.jpg `

Answer (score 0):

@Bright pyt Try php artisan serve command so it runs server for you.

Comment: I've run PHP artisan serve already the issue is npm run dev.

Comment: @Brightpyt Check your package.json file and find that you define any code for dev command or not. If not then add it first and then run npm run dev.

Comment: I didn't define any code. I've been using CMD to install and run codes. I'm new and following a tutorial online. But now,  I can't run the "npm run dev"

Comment: Please check the attached image for errors. Thanks